# Finding the convolution of a discrete function

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

It's been a while since I looked upon signals and systems so this might be a basic question, sorry, but I have trouble finding the answer to the next exercise:

Given $f(t)=-t+2 for \ t \in [1,2]$ and $f(t)=0 \ otherwise$
Calculate $f*f$;

I tried going with the definition, but the formed integer doesn't look right because I applied it like it was for continous functions.